# boto3 ec2.instance.filter tags output to json

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a python script that outputs EC2 instances based on a filter
and I have dictionary called `ec_info = {}` that I'm feeding data from `ec2.instances.filter()` output.

```
def get_instances():
    result = {}
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    data = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name':'tag:Project','Values': ['Web']}])
    for instance in data:
        for tag in instance.tags:
            if 'Name' in tag['Key']:
                name = tag['Value']
        ec2_info = {
             "Name": name,
             "Instance_Id": str(instance.id),
             "State": instance.state["Name"],
             "Private_IP": instance.private_ip_address,
             }
        data = json.dumps(ec2_info,indent=4,sort_keys=True)
        print(data)

get_instances()
```

as result I'm getting json output, but not as expected:

```
{
  "Instance_Id": "some_id",
  "Name": "some_name",
  "Private_IP": "ip",
  "State": "running"
}
{
  "Instance_Id": "some_id",
  "Name": "some_name",
  "Private_IP": "IP",
  "State": "running"
}
{
  "Instance_Id": "some_id",
  "Name": "some_name",
  "Private_IP": "ip",
  "State": "running"
}
```

I want to have this output:

```
{
  "Instance_Id": "some_id",
  "Name": "some_name",
  "Private_IP": "ip",
  "State": "running"

  "Instance_Id": "some_id",
  "Name": "some_name",
  "Private_IP": "IP",
  "State": "running"

  "Instance_Id": "some_id",
  "Name": "some_name",
  "Private_IP": "ip",
  "State": "running"
}
```

just one giant json output.

How can I do that?

Comment: The output you show is not valid JSON. You have multiple dictionary elements with the same Key (eg `Name`). The output from `ec2.instances.filter()` is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein so there is no way to fix that?

Comment: Well, you could code your Python program to output anything you want. However, please note that if you wish to consume that output as JSON, it would not work.

Comment: If you can specify what it is you would like to do with the output once you have it, we may be able to suggest a format that will be sufficient.

Comment: @Alex Well we have a home grown application for release team. These EC2's are for developers.. I would like to have them ability to start and stop the EC2's. Frontend is written is JS but backed is in AWS Lambdas. In order this to work the output must be in json but one whole json output

Comment: I've fixed it.  created array_result = [ ]  then array_result.append(ec2.info) and gives me valid json